# Why Kubernetes config file for ThingsBoard service use TCP for CoAP?

Tags: kubernetes, thingsboard, coap

I used Kubernetes on Google cloud platform for run the thingsboard service by following this step : https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/kubernetes/#tbyaml-file.

The problem is TB cannot receive the data when sent the data from NB-IoT Shield(BC95) by CoAP protocol on 5683 port. I have to see the Kubernetes configuration YAML in tb-service and found that 5683 port is defined by TCP protocol.

> clusterIP: 10.23.242.112   externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster   ports:
>     - name: ui
>       nodePort: 31146
>       port: 8080
>       protocol: TCP
>       targetPort: 8080
>     - name: mqtt
>       nodePort: 32758
>       port: 1883
>       protocol: TCP
>       targetPort: 1883
>     - name: coap
>       nodePort: 32343
>       port: 5683
>       protocol: TCP
>       targetPort: 5683

The question is the protocol of `CoAP` should be `UDP` or not?

Answer (score 0):

CoAP, by itself, can be run both over TCP and UDP (indicated by coap+tcp:// or coap:// URIs, respectively). As the BC95 only supports UDP as far as I can tell, you're using the latter.

As by [an example in a kubernetes issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19937), you may want to try setting the protocol family to UDP. There's use cases for both, which may be why there's a "TCP" in your setup (odd, though; the current examplein the docs does not have any "protocol: TCP" in it), but with this client you're probably using UDP.